# DD-WRT: dhcp6c not fetching new address for ppp0

Tags: ipv6, dd-wrt

I'm currently trying to configure my DD-WRT-based router to do IPv6. Now I'm at a point where it works fine - until the line is disconnected and reconnects (which happens at least every 24h... for a country renowned for its engineering, Germany is still surprisingly backwater when it comes to internet).

Not giving out static IP addresses, my provider requires me to fetch the configuration using DHCPv6, which I then propagate into to my localnet.
But when `ppp0` is disconnected and reconnected, `dhcp6c` does not fetch a new address and subsequently `radvd` does not advertise the change.

I created a script `/jffs/etc/config/ipv6.ipup` which restarts all the associated services and it works when I invoke it manually. So even though the documentation says that all `*.ipup` scripts in that directory should be automatically invoked when the configuration state of the WAN interface changes, it's apparently not happening.

Preferably I'd have `dhcp6c` and `radvd` notice the change automatically without completely restarting them, but if you know how any way to solve this configuration, I'd be grateful for any tips.

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/questions/742792/how-do-i-deploy-ipv6-within-a-lan-using-a-debian-based-router-and-prefix-delegat

Comment: The question not, but the answer gave me an idea nonetheless :) Thanks for the hint, I'll make certain to try it this evening!

Comment: I know - ancient - did you ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. At one point I switched to OpenWRT and there it worked without further configuration.